# Why have Laravel Middleware contracts been deprecated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, deprecated

I just discovered that Laravel 5.1 deprecated (and 5.2 removed) Middleware contracts. I used them for long time, but I have never noticed this removal.

Just a simple question, why?

Why do I have to define a method (`handle`) without any contract forces me to do this?

Comment: What the answer would boil down to would probably be "because the dev team thought they weren't necessary anymore".

Comment: Sure, but I hope there is a motivation about this decision...

Comment: I am also wondering about the motivation behind this. I prefer responding to inspection warnings over using artisan make commands.